Correspondence between the set of Riemannian metrics and $O(n)$-structures
I am more interested in the case where I have a $O(n)-$ structure and I want to find the correspondence metric. Picking a frame of $F(TM)$ is equivalent of picking a basis for $T_pM$. For example, we pick a frame $(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ where $X$ are linear isometries $\mathbb{R}^n\to TM$ and $X_1=X(e_1),\ldots, X_n=X(e_n) $ where the $e_i $ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then, is the corresponding metric's components $g_{ij}|_p=g(X_i|_p,X_j|_p)$ ?
I am a bit confused, where we use the $O(n)-$reduction ?
EDIT*
Coming back to the problem I had some thoughts, if $X\in O(n)$ then in terms of inner product $<Xu,Xv>=<u,v>$, where $u,v$ should be in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Then there is not a canonical choice, but there is always the usual inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
These are just some thought, since I can't seem to find a rigorous answer what the corresponding metric should be. As the comments pointed out, currently they don't make sense.

The sentence  "For example..." makes no sense as written. No wonder you are confused by it.

@MoisheKohan Thank you.

The question still makes no sense to me, I truly have no idea what are you trying to say, even though I know differential geometry quite well. My suggestion is to read a textbook, say, do Carmo's "Riemannian geometry". He does not use the language of reductions but at least you will learn the basics.

@MoisheKohan if i have a $O(n)$ structure how do i get the corresponding metric? That is basically the question.

Oh, then you should edit your question accordingly, it is actually quite easy, just linear algebra.

If you have an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, you can define a principal $O(n)$-bundle (which is an $O(n)$-reduction of the frame bundle $F(M)$)
$$
O(n)\to F_O(M)\to M
$$
whose fiber at $p\in M$ is the set of all orthonormal bases of $T_pM$. For $p\in M$ choose such an orthonormal basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)\in F_O(M)_p$. For $X,Y\in T_pM$ we can write $X=X^je_j$ and $Y=Y^je_j$. You can now recover the metric by
$$
g(X,Y)=X^iY^jg(e_i,e_j)=\sum_j X^jY^j. \tag1
$$
For the converse recall that local trivializations of a principal fiber bundle are in one-to-one correspondence with local sections of the bundle. So if you have an $O(n)$-reduction of the frame bundle $F(M)$ you have a bundle atlas $\mathcal A=\lbrace (U_i,\phi_i)\rbrace_{i\in I}$ with $O(n)$-valued transition maps. Each local trivialization $\phi_i$ corresponds to a local section $(E_1,\dots,E_n)$ of the frame bundle and you can just declare that $(E_1|_p,\dots,E_n|_p)$ is an orthonormal basis (w.r.t. the yet to be defined metric) of $T_pM$ for each $p\in U_i$. You can then define a metric using (1) as your definition. The fact that the transition maps of $\mathcal A$ are $O(n)$-valued shows, that this is well-defined.
